# Blender 2.82 Crashes often. What should I do?

Tags: texture-painting, file-browser

I am getting crashes with Blender 2.82 multiple times a day.  I cannot pin point a specific action.

For example it crashed a few minutes ago while attempting to save an image file.  Is there some actions I should not be taking in 2.82 or are there some known states of Blender which cause these crashes?

From the Blender.org website.

The following builds have the latest features and cool bug fixes. They can be unstable and mess up your files. Use at your own risk.

Comment: I also have issues, like crashes and totally black windows, even with small projects (Nvidia gtx 970, Windows 10 Pro).

Comment: The usual first step is to ensure that the graphics driver are updated. If the problem still occurs, you will have to find a step by step instructions how to reproduce the issue. A bug report can be created through *Help > Report a Bug* in Blender.