# Since 2.82 my computer completely crash on random occasions

Tags: error

I am using blender since 2.8 around October.

Since I installed 2.82 the software keep crashing together with my whole computer.
Not even a BSOD, the computer just reboot while I am modelling, or more recently while doing weight painting.

I deactivated most of the addons, and that have helped, but it is still crashing several times a day.
I even tried to get back to Blender 2.81 but the crash also occur with 2.81 now.

I believe all my drivers are up to date.

my configuration is:
windows 10 pro N 64bit

CPU intel core i7 4790 @ 3.6ghz

ram 16 gb DDR3 @ 798MHz

NVIDIA RTX 2070 gigabyte

I do not overclock anything.

I really have no idea what I could do to stop the crashing

Any one have an idea?

Comment: Could be a hardware issue. I would remove the graphics card and see if the problem persists. It could be a power issue or a graphics card issue (check the Windows Event Viewer after a crash).

Comment: NVIDIA. Could also be a problem with recent driver updates. I had those crashes frequently after driver updates until I switched to AMD.

Comment: I did change my graphic card about a month ago. But the crashes didn't start before february 17th after I installed 2.82. The event viewer mention error 41 kernel-power at every crash. I am not sure how to interpret this event. Is there a way to diagnostic that kind of error?
a power diagnostic tool?
a graphic card diagnostic tool? thanks for the help

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167937/blender-2-82-crashes-often-what-should-i-do

Comment: @metaphor_set AMD is definitely not the solution here. There are various issues with their graphics cards and software - it's the same thing if not worse. In fact, I solved the exact same problem of computer crashing while using CAD software in my co-worker's work PC by removing an AMD card. The problem could be anywhere. It is also likely to be in the motherboard as it probably was in my case, but changing graphics card was the easier solution.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys - this is very much opinion based. Also, the comment section is not the place to discuss the age-old "my  GPU is better than yours" question in lengthy case studies.

Comment: I am not discussing which is better, I am saying the brand is most likely not the cause (...despite Nvidia being better :D )

Comment: @batFINGER thanks for the link, yes and when the crash comes so randomly it's hard to make a bug rapport.

Comment: But, has anyone an idea how to test/diagnostic if it comes from the hardware?
I found a couple of software to test the graphic card. One called OCCT seems to test the power supply as well but I couldn't reproduce the crash.

The disturbing thing being that the crashes occurs in situations that don't demand any extra resource (i.e. moving a vertex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me this sounds like your graphic card uses more power than the power adaptor can deliver. And then the system becomes unstable. This would fit to your new graphics card and the kernel power error, even when it started with Blender 2.82 first. Have you checked if your power adaptor can deliver enough power to the system?

To calculate how strong a power adaptor needs to be, calculate the maximum watt values for all of your components in your pc together, and add 10% to 20% on top to have some reserve. There are some small users that are usually not worth a mentioning. A ssd usually uses around 2 watt. Same goes for ram. But a motherboard comsumes easily around 50 watt nowadays.

Comment: For the required PSU power supply you can also use online calculators to get an estimated value, such as the [BeQuiet Power Supply Calculator](https://www.bequiet.com/en/psucalculator).

Comment: OK thanks, I will try that :)

Comment: Just that i have asked, have you connected the graphics card correctly? Nowadays cards needs extra power from the power supply ...

Comment: yes I did put the extra power cable

Comment: Now I tried bequiet.com and it says:
"Your maximum wattage requirement 387" 
my power supply has several figures about max power, but basically it says 'max power 500w'
but apparently  max 420w on some output, max 470w on some others, and 103W on a third type

Comment: One strange thing is that those reboots happen when I am modelling, with MatCap or Flat shading. Nothing really intensive

Comment: It's too hard to make diagnostics from here. Can't you put the old graphics card in and test if the problem still exists? That would be the easiest test. If the problem is still there then you have a problem elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, it would be the best test indeed. I will do that when I have the time.